# regular expressions $(a+b)^*$

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

If I have a regular expression $(a+b)^*$, does that mean I can't have the string $abba$ because the expression ends with a $b$? Or does this expression accept every string in the alphabet $\{a, b\}$?

Comment: I edited you question in $\LaTeX$ but just to be sure, please confirm you were considering the regular expression $(a+b)^*$ and not $(a^+b)^*$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin yes, thank you

Answer (score 1):

(a+b)* = (b+a)* because "or" is commutative.

Comment: So would (a+b)* accept every string in the language {a, b}?

Comment: @user270494 yes, you can prove it by induction if you really are skeptical.

Comment: @user270494 The language $\{a,b\}$ contains just the two words of length $1$. You probably meant the language $\{a,b\}^*$.

Comment: @djechlin is (a+b) the same as (a|b)?

Comment: @user270494 that depends on how you define + and |. Check whichever textbook you're using.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression means that at every position in the string you may have either an $a$ or a $b$. That describes every possible string over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$.